# Catch HTTP Error 403.7 - Forbidden in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, error-handling

Is there any way I can redirect the user to a custom page whenever `HTTP Error 403.7 - Forbidden` occurs in my ASP.NET website?

Comment: How are you currently handling errors?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev I have the code on Application_Error on global.asax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use your web.config file to set a custom error page:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
    <error statusCode="403.7" redirect="~/ErrorPages/4037.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

Please see the following article

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2345/Custom-Errors-in-ASP-NET) is also worth a look.

**Edit**

From your comment I'd say that the status code need to be an integer so change it to:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
    <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/ErrorPages/403.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

**Edit 2**

You can also [set CustomError pages in IIS](http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/jamie-furr/how-to-create-custom-error-pages-in-iis-7-5-with-asp-net/). I'm not sure if it works with sub status though but it is worth a shot.

Comment: It's not working! It says `The value is invalid according to its data type int`!

Comment: Yes, the only way to set redirect pages for sub statuses is through IIS. Thx